# Why is ElementsService forgiving of an element type whose populateElementModel() method doesn’t return an actual element model

Tags: baseelementmodel

In the 2.3 release notes, one item reads:

> ElementsService is now forgiving of an element type whose populateElementModel() method doesn’t return an actual element model.

I'm curious what the use case is here — When would populateElementModel not return a BaseElementModel, and why would that be okay?

Answer (score 1):

Someone requested it. They had a use case for it where they couldn’t simply prevent the rows from getting selected in the DB query with a conditional (which is still definitely the recommended way to go). The only reason I decided to add it was for the sake of defensive coding.